# Using replace function with regex in C Sharp

Tags: c#, regex

Need some help on a problem please.

In fact I got a base64 string named "image" like that :

```
data:image/pjpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE...
```

I need to replace the part "data:image/pjpeg;base64," by "".

I try this way :

```
imageSrc = image.Replace("data:image/(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|pjpeg|x-png);base64,", "");
```

But it doesn't work.

Is somebody has an idea on that.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the static [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) method on the Regex class.

```
imageSrc  = Regex.Replace(image, "data:image/(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|pjpeg|x-png);base64,", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just using [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but you should use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for regular expressions.

---

But why not just use [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

```
imageSrc = image.Substring(image.IndexOf(',') + 1)
```

Since you know that your string is always starting with `data:image/...`, you don't need regular expressions at all.

Keep it simple and just take the substring after the first `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters your code is doing `String.Replace` instead of `Regex.Replace`.

```
imageSrc = Regex.Replace(image, "data:image/(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|pjpeg|x-png);base64,", "");
```

But Regex is a rather heavy for this use case, why not just take everything after the comma?

```
imageSrc = image.SubString(image.IndexOf(",") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

String.Replace() has no overload with regexp. Use Regex.Replace() instead.

Answer (score -1):

There is a mistake in your regex, you must specify **?:** for images alternatives and use Regex object, so :

```
Regex.Replace("data:image/(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg|pjpeg|x-png);base64,", "");
```

it should work

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the `?:` is not required. That operator only tells the Regex engine not to create a backreference. Your solution works, and is more efficient, but it is not correct to say the original Regex has a mistake. I still maintain that `Substring` is the best solution here. :)